# How to move within only one part of the page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I have read many answers written mainly by BalusC but still no luck.
  So I included via ajax rendering, a page in the part of the main page and it works perfect, whenever I click the button on the main bar the subpage xhtml is shown in the proper place. Now the problem is that i want to implement in that subpage a "selectOneMenu" so whenever a user clicks on one of the options he will be redirected to another xhtml which should appear on the same part of the page (instead of the previous page). I have already thought of many ideas to solve that(including conditional rendering), but I believe that there has to be much simpler and more correct way to solve it. Maybe JSF has some kind of container tag which could be used? 
PS
By the way that is my first post so sorry if I didnt make something clear.
UPDATE
It appeared to me that maybe I should somehow use ajax onValueChange which would read the value (via the actionListener ?) so when the user clicks on subpage the main page would read the value and render part with the new content. Is that even possible?

Comment: THX user1101422 for answering although, It appears that my lack of brightness led me to even asking this question. For the ones that could encounter similar problem(although i doubt it..) everything in between ui:composition tag behaves as it was a part of the page where it was included so the answer was to just render the panelGroup in which was include for that subpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueChange Listener to get the new value and in your bean using FacesContext you can redirect the page but make sure that you add ajax call to your selectonemenu if you dont want your page to refreshed.

```
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{some.value}"
    valueChangeListener="#{some.valuechanged}">
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{some.listen}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```